# What is the difference between 〜ている and 〜中?

Tags: grammar, tense

When we want to expresss that something is in progress, we can use the progressive form:

> 勉強している
>
> studying

But another way of expressing a progressing action is by adding 中 to the noun:

> 仕事中
>
> working

I want to know the difference between these two. Can I say 勉強中　or 仕事している to achieve the same meaning? If I can't, is there a pattern to this? I mean like what kind of nouns can I add 中 to?

I know that 勉強している is a verb while 仕事中 is an adverb but I don't care about the part of speech. I'm only considering it as a standalone word right now.

Comment: might be of interest: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/blog/2008/06/04/the-various-uses-of-%E3%80%8C%E4%B8%AD%E3%80%8D/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me, there is no big difference between 勉強しています and 勉強中です. It is just personal preference. [中]{ちゅう} can create idioms when combined with other nouns such as [工事中]{こうじちゅう} which means *under construction / repair* and you should note that it is a noun, not an adverb.

[中]{ちゅう} means *middle*. If you are in the middle of something, you are doing something. Therefore, 私は勉強中です is translated to

> I am in the middle of studying. / I am studying.

If you use [中]{ちゅう}, you can make the sentence more concise, but you have to note that it can't be used with all Japanese nouns.

Answer (score 2):

You can say 勉強中 or 仕事している. When the Japanese say a short phrase like 勉強している, it's frequently shortened as 勉強してる in a colloquial manner. Therefore, 仕事してる is more natural than 仕事している when you are asked by someone on a phone, etc.

○○中 is a very productive way to coin new words. 食事中, 旅行中, and 入院中 are a few examples of very common expressions of this type.

Comment: I don't think you really answered the question of what the difference between the two is.