# 中 to mean present continuous. Why 中?

Tags: grammar

Why is 中 used in:

```
送信中...
```

to mean that something is happening in the present moment. I see examples like this a lot.

Why 中 and not "-te iru"?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40598/what-is-the-difference-between-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-and-%E4%B8%AD

Answer (score 4):

For kanji compounds like 送信【そうしん】 or 工事【こうじ】 or 販売【はんばい】, you can't just add ている onto the end, since the base term is a noun.

This is vaguely like in English: you can't say *transmissioning*, or *constructioning*, or *saleing*, but you can say ***in** transmission*, or ***under** construction*, or ***on** sale*.  So instead of adding the *-ing*, you add the *in* or *on* or *under* (as appropriate for English usage).

In Japanese, you add the 中【ちゅう】, literally meaning "in the middle of *[whatever word just came before]*".

Comment: +1 But I wonder if the OP meant, why not 送信している?

Comment: `In Japanese, you add the 中ちゅう, literally meaning "in the middle of [whatever word just came before]".` ---> Is this true **only** for nouns?

Comment: @user3856370, good point, that's possibly what they meant.  If so, that's addressed by the link Leebo included in the comment on the initial question.

Comment: @Mareka, you cannot add 中【ちゅう】 to verbs, if that's what you're asking.  You _can_ add 中【なか】 after a verb to indicate something like the English _"while `[VERB]`-ing"_ or _"in the process of `[VERB]`-ing"_.  For example, see Google hits for [仕事【しごと】する中【なか】で](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E4%BB%95%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%A7%22) and [仕事【しごと】している中【なか】で](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E4%BB%95%E4%BA%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%A7%22).

Comment: @Mareka, there is also 中【じゅう】 that can attach to nouns with a meaning more like _"throughout"_, as in 一日中【いちにちじゅう】 _"throughout the day"_ or 体中【からだじゅう】 _"throughout the body"_.

Comment: I don't understand -- a) `you cannot add 中ちゅう to verbs` and b) `You can add 中なか after a verb`

Comment: @Mareka: If you're trying to say _"while `[VERB]`-ing"_ in Japanese, you cannot say _"`[VERB in plain or`_ `-te iru` _`form]` + chū"_.  You can say _"`[VERB in plain or`_ `-te iru` _`form]` + naka"_.  For example, 仕事【しごと】する中【ちゅう】 (_shigoto suru **chū**_) is incorrect, while 仕事【しごと】する中【なか】 (_shigoto suru **naka**_) is correct.